# How to use props type from a styled component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Sometimes I have a styled component like:

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledButton = styled.button;
```

And then I need to use it like this

```js
export default function CloseButton() {
  return <StyledButton>Close</StyledButton>
}
```

And use it like `<CloseButton />`.
But what if I need to use it like `<CloseButton onClick={doSomething} />`?
I would have to change my `CloseButton` component to:

```js
type Props = {
  onClick: () => void; 
}
export default function CloseButton(props: Props) {
  return <StyledButton onClick={props.onClick}>Close</StyledButton>
}
```

This sucks. So a better way would be just to pass all the props like:

```js
export default function CloseButton(props: any) {
  return <StyledButton {...props}>Close</StyledButton>
}
```

Thats clean and simple... but how to avoid `any` type of `props` and tell typescript to use props from StyledButton?

Comment: have you read https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#typescript?

Comment: @Peter I have read it. But the thing is that I would like to be able to use Props of specific Styled Component. For example: CloseButton should have all the <StyledButton> props, and StyledButton is `styled.button` so it uses props available in <button> element. In other places I would like to use <BigInput> with props from `styled.input`. I dont see any mentions of this kind of problem in Styled Components docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this:

```js
export default function CloseButton(props: typeof StyledButton.defaultProps) {
  return <StyledButton {...props}>Close</StyledButton>
}
```

is working almost perfect. It does show HTML attributes of a `<button>` element, although it does not show StyledComponents props like [as](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop) and [forwardAs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#forwardedas-prop)

Answer (score 1):

With Typescript you can access to a type field type by its key, like that:

```js
type MyObject = {
  value: number;
}

// same as : number
const v: MyObject['value'] = 6;
```

In your case, what you want:

```js
export default function CloseButton(props: StyledButton['props']) {
  return <StyledButton {...props}>Close</StyledButton>
}
```

It's quite usefull when you want to keep a type scoped, but allow to use it from another type.